# Resizing images in a ppt but not on first slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Resizing images in a ppt but i don't want it to apply on first slide of presentation what change should i make?

[image]

Comment: Please, edit your question and copy the code as text. It is easy to adapt it but I do not want to reproduce it looking to a picture...

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar in VBA for Excel only, so I may can't give you an exact code.
You should insert an "if" after the first For statement, checking the "osld" name or index - if it is the 1st slide, skip the resizing part of your code. (Probably index of the 1st slide is 0? Please check in PP)

e.g.

```
if osld.SlideIndex <> 1 then 
    for each opic in ...
    next
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try adapting your code in this way:

```
'YOUR CODE
'...
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If osld.SlideID <> ActivePresentation.Slides(1).SlideID Then
        For Each opic in osld.Shapes
            'Do here what your existing code does
        Next
    End If
next
'your existing code
```

Instead of `SlideID` you can also use `SlideIndex` or `SlideNumber`.